# A way to store relative dates in string form

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a scheduler that will fire a task *T*, and some of the parameters to *T* are very dependent on the date. For example, if *T* is run on a Tuesday, some of the parameters would be:

```
param1 = datetime('Monday at 1pm')
param2 = datetime('Tuesday at 1am')
```

The parameters can vary depending on when *T* is run. So, for example, if it's run on Sunday, the parameters could be:

```
param1 = datetime('Saturday at 12pm')
param2 = datetime('Sunday at 12pm')
```

And so on. The idea is that the dates are relative to when *T* is run, but I can't use `timedelta` because I don't know exactly when the task will be run, so I want to retain a degree of absolute control over the dates.

Now, the code that will start *T* has a little json package that specifies the parameters. I am in the process of writing a tiny scripting language that would allow me to specify relative date. It would look something along the lines of:

```
date1: { 
    'type': 'datetime', 
    'source': 'composite', 
    'value': '(Yn)-(Mn)-(Dn)-(Hn)-(Nn)'
}
```

The `value` string would be parsed and based on what's in the brackets, the parameters will be compiled. So, for example, if `value` is something like `(Y:n)-(M:n)-(D:-1)-(H:18)-(N:00)`, it would construct the date with current year, current month, the **previous** day, 18:00.

Am I trying to re-invent the wheel with some of this stuff. Are there libraries that will make my life easier?

---

EDIT: Looks like [Relative Delta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) from Date-Utils does exactly what I was describing above!

Comment: *I can't use `timedelta`...* - doesn't the scheduler know when it chooses to run the task?

Comment: @ire_and_curses: It sort of does: because I have many different types of tasks, instead of many recurring tasks, I have a generic regular task that fires off jobs that are outstanding. But that's not the issue: I need to be able to specify the times in parameters exactly. The task may run with a bit of jitter.

Answer (score 3):

For human readable date/time parsing, you may use [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime)

I would store the "human readable" string as is, and evaluate it when needed.

Comment: This looks like a powerful library but it's not very well documented :(